# ¿Cómo indexar columnas tipo JSON en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Cuando creamos una tabla en MySQL, generalmente revisamos, que columnas son las indicadas para indexar y de este modo ayudar a realizar las búsquedas mas rápido

*EJEMPLO*

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE profile(
    -> id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    -> INDEX(name),
    -> attributes JSON NOT NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.34 sec)
```

Este es uno de los modos para indicar que la columna name se debe indexar, por que es una cadena de texto contenida

Sin embargo los datos de tipo JSON, siguen una estructura similar a la siguiente

```
'{"data": {"name": "alfredo", "age": 20, "email": "mail@mail.com"}}'
```

*Llegados a este punto debemos respondernos lo siguiente*

1. Como se indexa una columna que guarda valores por clave/valor
2. Como se indexa el valor de una columna en especifico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo con el mismo ejemplo, tenemos la siguiente tabla

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE profile(
    -> id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    -> attributes JSON NOT NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.34 sec)
```

Sin embargo, al tener una columna JSON de este tipo

```
'{"name": "alfredo", "age": 20, "email": "mail@mail.com"}'
```

Debemos pensar primero en que tendremos que trabajar en columnas generadas, donde se almacene el valor de la clave/valor indexada

Primero creamos la nueva columna a la cual le indicamos el tipo, la longitud y con un alias la indicamos que clave del JSON va a contener

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE profile
    -> ADD attributes_data VARCHAR(150)
    -> AS (attributes->>"$.name");
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.27 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

***Qué es ese operador ->>?***

1. Es el operador acortado de la función `JSON_EXTRACT()`

Bien ahora que ya tenemos la columna generada, debemos indicar que al tener ya solo un valor almacenado `name` este mismo será indexado

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE profile
    -> ADD INDEX(attributes_data);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.72 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

1. Generamos una nueva columna(generated column) esta es la que guardara los datos de una sola clave de nuestro *JSON* es como una columna con datos filtrados
2. usamos el operador ->> que es el acortado de `JSON_EXTRACT()` para indicar que clave del JSON debe extraer, además lleva doble signo de mayor que, para evitar que las cadenas de texto las regrese entre comilladaas
3. Una vez que hemos creado la columna anterior, hacemos un `ALTER` indicando que esta columna será indexada

**actualización**

Si deseas usar la función `JSON_EXTRACT()` quedaría de este modo

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE profile
    -> ADD attributes_skills VARCHAR(150)
    -> AS (JSON_EXTRACT('attributes', '$.skills'));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.43 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**finalmente hagamos un describe de la tabla recién creada para checar las características que posee**

```
mysql> describe profile;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra             |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
| id                | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment    |
| name              | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                   |
| attributes        | json         | NO   |     | NULL    |                   |
| attributes_skills | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    | VIRTUAL GENERATED |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```